# Using a ordered factor as timevar in Motion Chart

Tags: r, googlevis

I have some data like this:

```
  time var1 var2 idvar
1   Q1    1    4     A
2   Q1    2    3     B
3   Q2    3    2     A
4   Q2    4    1     B
```

I need to make a `MotionChart` using each quarter (`Q1` and `Q2`) as a time var. I have tried to make `df$time`an ordered factor, but it still gives me an error as the `timevar` needs to be in numeric or date format. Is there any workaround with this? My actual data spans several years and all 4 quarters of each year in the `YYYYQn` format, which I would not like to change.

The code I'm using in this example:

```
library(googleVis)

df = data.frame(time = c("Q1","Q1","Q2","Q2"),var1 = c(1,2,3,4),var2=c(4,3,2,1),idvar=c("A","B","A","B"))
df$time =  ordered(df$time)
g = gvisMotionChart(df,timevar="time",idvar="idvar")
```

The output is an error:

```
Error : The timevar has to be of numeric or Date format. Currently it is  orderedThe timevar has to be of numeric or Date format. Currently it is  factor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you converted to `factor`? the documentation says that `timevar` argument can't handle factor. It can handle `character` if and only if they are in a **particular** format, that is (for example): `2010Q1`. Of course it can handle `Date`.

Here is my solution:
I just create a new column with transform where I paste the year (which you have to know, otherwise you could use a proxy) to all the `Q1`, `Q2` etc. it won't be hard by using recycling rules I think, here is just a little example.
After that I convert that column into `character`.

```
transform(df, time2 = paste(2010, df$time, sep = "")) -> df1
df1$time2 <- as.character(df1$time2)
```

The `df1` will be like that:

```
 df1
  time var1 var2 idvar  time2
1   Q1    1    4     A 2010Q1
2   Q1    2    3     B 2010Q1
3   Q2    3    2     A 2010Q2
4   Q2    4    1     B 2010Q2
```

After that you can use your code:

```
 g = gvisMotionChart(df1,timevar="time2",idvar="idvar")
```

produces this plot (with `plot(g)`):
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Since the error message stated that the function only accepted numeric or date formats, it didn't cross my mind to work with character (factor is chosen automatically when I use read.table in my actual data)

Comment: @Bernardo you can avoid (a piece) of my solution with the very useful `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when load the data. This argument does what it says *strings as factor* , with `FALSE` you'll have characters by default.

Comment: You are right, I completely forgot about this argument! One last thing, do you mind to explain the "It can handle character if and only if they are in a particular format" part? What exactly is this format?

Comment: @Bernardo the documentation says that the function is able to recognize character stings if formatted like examples: `'2010Q1` for quarterly and `'2010W04'` for weekly data.