# Reading date as a character in googlevis

Tags: r, rstudio, googlevis

so this is in reference to an earlier question: [Using a ordered factor as timevar in Motion Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146212/using-a-ordered-factor-as-timevar-in-motion-chart) but it wouldn't let me leave this as a comment :/

So, I am having the same error the person earlier was having, thing is, according to the answer: "the documentation says that timevar argument can't handle factor. It can handle character if and only if they are in a particular format, that is (for example): 2010Q1." Thing is, I already have my data formatted like that, in a csv file: http://www.filedropper.com/texasgdp

```
Time      GDP
2006Q1    500
2006Q2   1000
2006Q3   2000
2006Q4   2600....etc
```

So, if this is the character format, why am i still getting the same error? Is there a way I could just have rstudio reread that entire column as a "character" rather than a factor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this as you read the data in:

```
read.csv('file path',stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Or you can convert the column to a character vector after reading the data:

```
df$Time <- as.character(df$Time)
```